# Unity 3D multiple UV sets

Tags: import, unity-game-engine, maya

I have created an object that has the texture and an AO , they are on different UV sets in maya(with Layered Texture) and in maya the mash looks ok.

How do i achive the same effect in Unity3D?

I can not make unity use the 2nd UV set.

Comment: None of Unity's built-in shaders use UV2 for anything but lightmapping. You'll need to write your own shader.

Comment: There are lots of shaders available in the Unity Asset Store. It's possible there's already one that uses UV2 for AO. Might cost a little, but probably cheaper than investing days learning shader programming. (this one mentions vertex AO support https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/#/content/8880 . Might be able to contact them to confirm it does what you want.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to write a shader that does this. Here's a very minimal example, but you'd probably need to have a more elaborate setup for things specular, etc.

```
    Shader "Custom/twotex" {
        Properties {
            _MainTex ("Base (RGB)", 2D) = "white" {}
            _AoTex ("AO (RGB)", 2D) = "white" {}

        }
        SubShader {
            Tags { "RenderType"="Opaque" }
            LOD 200

            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma surface surf Lambert

            sampler2D _MainTex;
            sampler2D _AoTex;


            struct Input {
                float2 uv_MainTex : TEXCOORD0;
                float2 uv_AoTex :   TEXCOORD1;
            };

            void surf (Input IN, inout SurfaceOutput o) {
                half4 c = tex2D (_MainTex, IN.uv_MainTex.xy);
                half4 ao = tex2D (_AoTex, IN.uv_AoTex.xy);
                o.Albedo = c.rgb * ao.rgb;
                o.Alpha = c.a;
            }
            ENDCG
        } 
        FallBack "Diffuse"
    }
```

Comment: For those who need more info on it  I just changed it so it uses the 2nd UV set from the mesh and added a slider to control the intencity ( changed the folowing float2 uv_AoTex :   TEXCOORD1; -> float2 uv2_AoTex :   TEXCOORD1; and half4 ao = tex2D (_AoTex, IN.uv_AoTex.xy);) -> half4 ao = tex2D (_AoTex, IN.uv2_AoTex.xy);)

Comment: By the way i just noticed that it doeasnt reads the Alpha channel , I modifyed so it would be  "#pragma surface surf Lambert alpha" but then the whole mesh is semi transparent, here is a link [link](http://imageshack.us/a/img849/6179/dml8.jpg) , The image in the right has no Ao.

Comment: Do you want alpha transparency? The example above should work if the pragma line includes alpha; but what you get depends on what's in the alpha channel of the main main. If you don't want transparency use o.Alpha = 1; Is it possible your alpha channel is reversed?

Comment: This doeasn't just happen on transparency , a simple diffuse texture without any alpha map or transparency in it does the same effect, until now i could resolve it by using cutout transparency but now whit this shader can not get around it like that.

Comment: @eblue It's definitely the 2 after uv2_AoTex that makes it work, without that it just uses uv channel 1... very odd.